# Enabling docker module for Kibana

Tags: docker, kibana

After loggin into my docker container, I run the following commands to install docker Metricbeat module:

$  curl -L -O https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/beats/metricbeat/metricbeat-6.4.0-x86_64.rpm

$ rpm -vi metricbeat-6.4.0-x86_64.rpm

$ metricbeat modules enable docker
Module docker doesn't exist!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a known issue with metricbeat-6.4.0
See https://github.com/elastic/beats/issues/8104

Take metricbeat-6.4.1